# Real Machine randomly refuses to start

Tags: boot, power, power-supply

Folks I`m completely clueless. I have a machine with the configurations above. By some strange reason at random times it refuses to boot, fans will spin but seems no power enough is generated to get to post (this is the perceived effect I cannot prove it as for now I found no alteration on tension measurements on the fountain). As my power unit was 5 years old I replaced it for a new one with 750Watts (real) still at random times the machine wont turn on. This happens even when the machine is cold (ie not used for days) it does not seem to do if I booted last time in windows or linux.

A technician suggested me replace my HDMI cable from the GPU to the monitor for a DVI one, I sincerelly see no correlation on the swap regarding boot efficiency. Removing the gpu also seemed to make no difference. What I did notince after changinf the power unity is that I always have the machine to turn on, sometimes I do not get to the post step but I do get fans spinning.

Any ideas?

```
    description: Desktop Computer
    product: System Product Name (To Be Filled By O.E.M.)
    vendor: System manufacturer
    version: System Version
    serial: System Serial Number
    width: 64 bits
    capabilities: smbios-2.5 dmi-2.5 vsyscall32
    configuration: boot=normal chassis=desktop family=To Be Filled By O.E.M. sku=To Be Filled By O.E.M. uuid=60A2A7DC-8EFE-D511-905A-BCAEC5BEB3A2
  *-core
       description: Motherboard
       product: M4A88T-M
       vendor: ASUSTeK Computer INC.
       physical id: 0
       version: Rev X.0x
       serial: MF70B1G07301491
       slot: To Be Filled By O.E.M.
     *-firmware
          description: BIOS
          vendor: American Megatrends Inc.
          physical id: 0
          version: 2402
          date: 12/01/2010
          size: 64KiB
          capacity: 1984KiB
          capabilities: isa pci pnp apm upgrade shadowing escd cdboot bootselect socketedrom edd int13floppy1200 int13floppy720 int13floppy2880 int5printscreen int9keyboard int14serial int17printer int10video acpi usb ls120boot zipboot biosbootspecification
     *-cpu
          description: CPU
          product: (To Be Filled By O.E.M.)
          vendor: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD]
          physical id: 4
          bus info: cpu@0
          version: AMD Phenom(tm) II X6 1090T Processor
          serial: To Be Filled By O.E.M.
          slot: AM3
          size: 1600MHz
          capacity: 3600MHz
          width: 64 bits
          clock: 200MHz
          capabilities: x86-64 fpu fpu_exception wp vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush mmx fxsr sse sse2 ht syscall nx mmxext fxsr_opt pdpe1gb rdtscp 3dnowext 3dnow constant_tsc rep_good nopl nonstop_tsc extd_apicid aperfmperf pni monitor cx16 popcnt lahf_lm cmp_legacy svm extapic cr8_legacy abm sse4a misalignsse 3dnowprefetch osvw ibs skinit wdt cpb hw_pstate npt lbrv svm_lock nrip_save pausefilter vmmcall cpufreq
          configuration: cores=6 enabledcores=6
        *-cache:0
             description: L1 cache
             physical id: 5
             slot: L1-Cache
             size: 768KiB
             capacity: 768KiB
             capabilities: pipeline-burst internal varies data
        *-cache:1
             description: L2 cache
             physical id: 6
             slot: L2-Cache
             size: 3MiB
             capacity: 3MiB
             capabilities: pipeline-burst internal varies unified
        *-cache:2
             description: L3 cache
             physical id: 7
             slot: L3-Cache
             size: 6MiB
             capacity: 6MiB
             capabilities: pipeline-burst internal varies unified
     *-memory
          description: System Memory
          physical id: 33
          slot: System board or motherboard
          size: 8GiB
        *-bank:0
             description: DIMM Synchronous 1333 MHz (0.8 ns)
             product: PartNum0
             vendor: Manufacturer0
             physical id: 0
             serial: SerNum0
             slot: DIMM0
             size: 2GiB
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 1333MHz (0.8ns)
        *-bank:1
             description: DIMM Synchronous 1333 MHz (0.8 ns)
             product: PartNum1
             vendor: Manufacturer1
             physical id: 1
             serial: SerNum1
             slot: DIMM1
             size: 2GiB
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 1333MHz (0.8ns)
        *-bank:2
             description: DIMM Synchronous 1333 MHz (0.8 ns)
             product: PartNum2
             vendor: Manufacturer2
             physical id: 2
             serial: SerNum2
             slot: DIMM2
             size: 2GiB
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 1333MHz (0.8ns)
        *-bank:3
             description: DIMM Synchronous 1333 MHz (0.8 ns)
             product: PartNum3
             vendor: Manufacturer3
             physical id: 3
             serial: SerNum3
             slot: DIMM3
             size: 2GiB
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 1333MHz (0.8ns)
     *-pci:0
          description: Host bridge
          product: RS880 Host Bridge
          vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
          physical id: 100
          bus info: pci@0000:00:00.0
          version: 00
          width: 32 bits
          clock: 66MHz
        *-pci:0
             description: PCI bridge
             product: RS780 PCI to PCI bridge (ext gfx port 0)
             vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
             physical id: 2
             bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
             version: 00
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pci pm pciexpress msi ht normal_decode bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=pcieport
             resources: irq:24 ioport:d000(size=4096) memory:fc000000-febfffff ioport:d4000000(size=201326592)
           *-display
                description: VGA compatible controller
                product: GF114 [GeForce GTX 560 Ti]
                vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
                physical id: 0
                bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
                version: a1
                width: 64 bits
                clock: 33MHz
                capabilities: pm msi pciexpress vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
                configuration: driver=nvidia latency=0
                resources: irq:27 memory:fc000000-fdffffff memory:d8000000-dfffffff memory:d4000000-d7ffffff ioport:dc00(size=128) memory:feb00000-feb7ffff
           *-multimedia
                description: Audio device
                product: GF114 HDMI Audio Controller
                vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
                physical id: 0.1
                bus info: pci@0000:01:00.1
                version: a1
                width: 32 bits
                clock: 33MHz
                capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
                configuration: driver=snd_hda_intel latency=0
                resources: irq:19 memory:febf8000-febfbfff
        *-pci:1
             description: PCI bridge
             product: RS780/RS880 PCI to PCI bridge (PCIE port 5)
             vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
             physical id: a
             bus info: pci@0000:00:0a.0
             version: 00
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pci pm pciexpress msi ht normal_decode bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=pcieport
             resources: irq:25 ioport:e000(size=4096) ioport:faf00000(size=1048576)
           *-network
                description: Ethernet interface
                product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
                vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
                physical id: 0
                bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
                logical name: eth0
                version: 06
                serial: bc:ae:c5:be:b3:a2
                size: 1Gbit/s
                capacity: 1Gbit/s
                width: 64 bits
                clock: 33MHz
                capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
                configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=full firmware=rtl_nic/rtl8168e-2.fw ip=192.168.1.14 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=MII speed=1Gbit/s
                resources: irq:26 ioport:e800(size=256) memory:fafff000-faffffff memory:faff8000-faffbfff
        *-storage
             description: SATA controller
             product: SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 SATA Controller [IDE mode]
             vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
             physical id: 11
             bus info: pci@0000:00:11.0
             version: 00
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 66MHz
             capabilities: storage pm ahci_1.0 bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=ahci latency=64
             resources: irq:22 ioport:c000(size=8) ioport:b000(size=4) ioport:a000(size=8) ioport:9000(size=4) ioport:8000(size=16) memory:fbfffc00-fbffffff
        *-usb:0
             description: USB controller
             product: SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 USB OHCI0 Controller
             vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
             physical id: 12
             bus info: pci@0000:00:12.0
             version: 00
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 66MHz
             capabilities: ohci bus_master
             configuration: driver=ohci-pci latency=64
             resources: irq:16 memory:fbffe000-fbffefff
           *-usbhost
                product: OHCI PCI host controller
                vendor: Linux 3.18.2-2-ARCH ohci_hcd
                physical id: 1
                bus info: usb@3
                logical name: usb3
                version: 3.18
                capabilities: usb-1.10
                configuration: driver=hub slots=3 speed=12Mbit/s
              *-usb
                   description: Generic USB device
                   product: Xbox 360 Wireless Receiver for Windows
                   vendor: Microsoft Corp.
                   physical id: 2
                   bus info: usb@3:2
                   version: 1.07
                   capabilities: usb-2.00
                   configuration: driver=xpad maxpower=260mA speed=12Mbit/s
        *-usb:1
             description: USB controller
             product: SB7x0 USB OHCI1 Controller
             vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
             physical id: 12.1
             bus info: pci@0000:00:12.1
             version: 00
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 66MHz
             capabilities: ohci bus_master
             configuration: driver=ohci-pci latency=64
             resources: irq:16 memory:fbffd000-fbffdfff
           *-usbhost
                product: OHCI PCI host controller
                vendor: Linux 3.18.2-2-ARCH ohci_hcd
                physical id: 1
                bus info: usb@4
                logical name: usb4
                version: 3.18
                capabilities: usb-1.10
                configuration: driver=hub slots=3 speed=12Mbit/s
              *-usb:0
                   description: Keyboard
                   product: Razer BlackWidow
                   vendor: Razer
                   physical id: 1
                   bus info: usb@4:1
                   version: 2.00
                   capabilities: usb-2.00
                   configuration: driver=usbhid maxpower=100mA speed=12Mbit/s
              *-usb:1
                   description: Mouse
                   product: Razer DeathAdder
                   vendor: Razer
                   physical id: 2
                   bus info: usb@4:2
                   version: 1.00
                   capabilities: usb-2.00
                   configuration: driver=usbhid maxpower=100mA speed=12Mbit/s
        *-usb:2
             description: USB controller
             product: SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 USB EHCI Controller
             vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
             physical id: 12.2
             bus info: pci@0000:00:12.2
             version: 00
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 66MHz
             capabilities: pm debug ehci bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=ehci-pci latency=64
             resources: irq:17 memory:fbfff800-fbfff8ff
           *-usbhost
                product: EHCI Host Controller
                vendor: Linux 3.18.2-2-ARCH ehci_hcd
                physical id: 1
                bus info: usb@1
                logical name: usb1
                version: 3.18
                capabilities: usb-2.00
                configuration: driver=hub slots=6 speed=480Mbit/s
              *-usb:0
                   description: Video
                   product: Microsoft
                   vendor: Microsoft
                   physical id: 3
                   bus info: usb@1:3
                   version: 1.00
                   capabilities: usb-2.00
                   configuration: driver=snd-usb-audio maxpower=500mA speed=480Mbit/s
              *-usb:1
                   description: Mass storage device
                   product: SimpleDrive USB 2.0
                   vendor: HitachiGST
                   physical id: 6
                   bus info: usb@1:6
                   version: 0.00
                   serial: D20103400D2A
                   capabilities: usb-2.00 scsi
                   configuration: driver=usb-storage maxpower=2mA speed=480Mbit/s
        *-usb:3
             description: USB controller
             product: SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 USB OHCI0 Controller
             vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
             physical id: 13
             bus info: pci@0000:00:13.0
             version: 00
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 66MHz
             capabilities: ohci bus_master
             configuration: driver=ohci-pci latency=64
             resources: irq:18 memory:fbffc000-fbffcfff
           *-usbhost
                product: OHCI PCI host controller
                vendor: Linux 3.18.2-2-ARCH ohci_hcd
                physical id: 1
                bus info: usb@5
                logical name: usb5
                version: 3.18
                capabilities: usb-1.10
                configuration: driver=hub slots=3 speed=12Mbit/s
              *-usb
                   description: Audio device
                   product: Logitech G930 Headset
                   vendor: Logitech
                   physical id: 1
                   bus info: usb@5:1
                   version: 1.00
                   capabilities: usb-1.10 audio-control
                   configuration: driver=usbhid maxpower=100mA speed=12Mbit/s
        *-usb:4
             description: USB controller
             product: SB7x0 USB OHCI1 Controller
             vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
             physical id: 13.1
             bus info: pci@0000:00:13.1
             version: 00
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 66MHz
             capabilities: ohci bus_master
             configuration: driver=ohci-pci latency=64
             resources: irq:18 memory:fbffb000-fbffbfff
           *-usbhost
                product: OHCI PCI host controller
                vendor: Linux 3.18.2-2-ARCH ohci_hcd
                physical id: 1
                bus info: usb@6
                logical name: usb6
                version: 3.18
                capabilities: usb-1.10
                configuration: driver=hub slots=3 speed=12Mbit/s
        *-usb:5
             description: USB controller
             product: SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 USB EHCI Controller
             vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
             physical id: 13.2
             bus info: pci@0000:00:13.2
             version: 00
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 66MHz
             capabilities: pm debug ehci bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=ehci-pci latency=64
             resources: irq:19 memory:fbfff400-fbfff4ff
           *-usbhost
                product: EHCI Host Controller
                vendor: Linux 3.18.2-2-ARCH ehci_hcd
                physical id: 1
                bus info: usb@2
                logical name: usb2
                version: 3.18
                capabilities: usb-2.00
                configuration: driver=hub slots=6 speed=480Mbit/s
        *-serial UNCLAIMED
             description: SMBus
             product: SBx00 SMBus Controller
             vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
             physical id: 14
             bus info: pci@0000:00:14.0
             version: 3c
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 66MHz
             capabilities: ht cap_list
             configuration: latency=0
        *-ide
             description: IDE interface
             product: SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 IDE Controller
             vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
             physical id: 14.1
             bus info: pci@0000:00:14.1
             version: 00
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 66MHz
             capabilities: ide msi bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=pata_atiixp latency=64
             resources: irq:16 ioport:1f0(size=8) ioport:3f6 ioport:170(size=8) ioport:376 ioport:ff00(size=16)
        *-multimedia
             description: Audio device
             product: SBx00 Azalia (Intel HDA)
             vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
             physical id: 14.2
             bus info: pci@0000:00:14.2
             version: 00
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pm bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=snd_hda_intel latency=64
             resources: irq:16 memory:fbff4000-fbff7fff
        *-isa
             description: ISA bridge
             product: SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 LPC host controller
             vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
             physical id: 14.3
             bus info: pci@0000:00:14.3
             version: 00
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 66MHz
             capabilities: isa bus_master
             configuration: latency=0
        *-pci:2
             description: PCI bridge
             product: SBx00 PCI to PCI Bridge
             vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
             physical id: 14.4
             bus info: pci@0000:00:14.4
             version: 00
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 66MHz
             capabilities: pci subtractive_decode bus_master
        *-usb:6
             description: USB controller
             product: SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 USB OHCI2 Controller
             vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
             physical id: 14.5
             bus info: pci@0000:00:14.5
             version: 00
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 66MHz
             capabilities: ohci bus_master
             configuration: driver=ohci-pci latency=64
             resources: irq:18 memory:fbffa000-fbffafff
           *-usbhost
                product: OHCI PCI host controller
                vendor: Linux 3.18.2-2-ARCH ohci_hcd
                physical id: 1
                bus info: usb@7
                logical name: usb7
                version: 3.18
                capabilities: usb-1.10
                configuration: driver=hub slots=2 speed=12Mbit/s
     *-pci:1
          description: Host bridge
          product: Family 10h Processor HyperTransport Configuration
          vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
          physical id: 101
          bus info: pci@0000:00:18.0
          version: 00
          width: 32 bits
          clock: 33MHz
     *-pci:2
          description: Host bridge
          product: Family 10h Processor Address Map
          vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
          physical id: 102
          bus info: pci@0000:00:18.1
          version: 00
          width: 32 bits
          clock: 33MHz
     *-pci:3
          description: Host bridge
          product: Family 10h Processor DRAM Controller
          vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
          physical id: 103
          bus info: pci@0000:00:18.2
          version: 00
          width: 32 bits
          clock: 33MHz
     *-pci:4
          description: Host bridge
          product: Family 10h Processor Miscellaneous Control
          vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
          physical id: 104
          bus info: pci@0000:00:18.3
          version: 00
          width: 32 bits
          clock: 33MHz
          configuration: driver=k10temp
          resources: irq:0
     *-pci:5
          description: Host bridge
          product: Family 10h Processor Link Control
          vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
          physical id: 105
          bus info: pci@0000:00:18.4
          version: 00
          width: 32 bits
          clock: 33MHz
  *-scsi
       physical id: 1
       bus info: scsi@6
       logical name: scsi6
       capabilities: scsi-host
       configuration: driver=usb-storage
```

PS:
Ive tried moving RAM slots around no change.

Answer (score 0):

I would try removing every component that isn't absolutely necessary. Unplug things like PCI cards, DVD drives, etc and see if the problem persists. If it does not, then you can try to slowly add them back into the mix.

They make "Post cards" for situations like this. Not the medium of exchange for mailing letters... but a PCI or PCI-E card with LED indicators with a two digit code that will tell you the problem. You can look up that code and it should tell you at which stage in the machine is failing to boot up.

You can find various options here:

http://www.newegg.com/Product/ProductList.aspx?Submit=ENE&DEPA=0&Order=BESTMATCH&Description=post+card&N=-1&isNodeId=1

Answer (score 0):

Extending @Super1337 very clear debugging help to a yet more exact one:

1. Unplug *everything* what you can, and check if it is okay.
2. If not, your motherboard is unreparably damaged.
3. If yes, plug all one by one again, to see, by which device will it bad again.
4. If this is not enough to determine, which device could cause that, it is your motherboards problem again (goto 2).

A common problem of the printed circuits of the current computers, that *power* must go many times on the very think copper films between its layers. For a simple chip it can be okay, but for example, on USB slots it is soon problematic. This is because why so many usb devices have a plug for external power, too, and this is cause why so many hardware elements needs a power cord coming directly from your power supply.

Unfortunately, the power problems cause mostly the worst debuggable, and most mystical hardware problems. In your case, the probable cause of the problem is that your hardware tries to get abnormally many power on boot, which sometimes can flow through the thin copper layer of your motherboard, and sometimes not, it depends on a pseudorandom hazard cases.

P.s. sometimes buggy BIOS updates can cause similar problems, too. I suggest a bios upgrade, and a switch to a new motherboard battery.

Answer (score 0):

Okay guys I did as suggested and after many struggles I found out one of my dissipators on the mobo.

[image: The one with the ASUS written on it] . When applying manual pressure to it the machine would boot. I ended up replacing mobo and processor aso the machine is now fine.